# How to quickly jump to a directory in emacs?

Tags: commands, directories

Say I have a project directory called "project". In the directory there are two directories "mini1" and "mini2". Suppose my active buffer is deep within a subdirectory in "mini1". Is there a way to make a C-f like binding where the pre-existing directory text is /project/mini2/ and not the deeply nested directory under mini1 that I'm in?

Comment: I'm a fan of [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) for working with projects. Might be worth a look.

Comment: You can check out [Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper)—you hit `C-x f` and then if you hit `DEL 2 /` you should have `mini2/` selected just how the autocomplete works.

Comment: And, of course, you can always make a macro/function to do that for a specific directory.

Comment: The question is too vague. How do you expect to communicate the desired target directory to your command?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find-directory-in-project-by-selected` from https://github.com/technomancy/find-file-in-project

I also wrote a prototype in pure Lisp. It does not use any third party command line program or package,

```
(require 'find-lisp)
(require 'dired)
(require 'ido)

(defun my-open-dir-in-project ()
  "Open directory in project."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((root (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".git"))
         (input-regex (read-string "Input regex (or press ENTER): "))
         (ignored-regex ".*/\\.git\\|.*/\\.svn\\|.*/\\.bzr")
         (find-lisp-regexp (if (string= input-regex "") ".*" input-regex))
         (cands (find-lisp-find-files-internal
                 root
                 'find-lisp-file-predicate-is-directory
                 'find-lisp-default-directory-predicate))
         selected)

    (when cands
      (setq cands
            (delq nil
                  (mapcar `(lambda (c)
                             (unless (string-match-p ,ignored-regex c) c))
                          cands)))

      (setq selected (and cands
                          ;; `ido-completing-read' could be replaced with `ivy-read'
                          (ido-completing-read (format "directories %s: " root)
                                               cands))))
    (when selected
      (switch-to-buffer (dired selected)))))
```